# Memory issue while fetching images from Photos library with metadata

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to get all photos from photos library with image's metadata. It works fine for 10-20 images but when there are 50+ images it occupies too much memory, which causes to app crash.

**Why i need all images into array?**
**Answer** - to send images to server app. [i'm using GCDAsyncSocket to send data on receiver socket/port and i don't have that much waiting time to request images from PHAsset while sending images on socket/port.

My Code :

```
+(void)getPhotosDataFromCamera:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *arrImageData))completionHandler
{
    [PhotosManager checkPhotosPermission:^(bool granted)
    {
        if (granted)
        {
            NSMutableArray *arrImageData = [NSMutableArray new];

        NSArray *arrImages=[[NSArray alloc] init];

        PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];

        NSLog(@"%d",(int)result.count);

        arrImages = [result copy];

        //--- If no images.
        if (arrImages.count <= 0)
        {
            completionHandler(nil);
            return ;
        }

        __block int index = 1;
        __block BOOL isDone = false;
        for (PHAsset *asset in arrImages)
        {
            [PhotosManager requestMetadata:asset withCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *metadata)
             {
                 @autoreleasepool
                 {
                     NSData *imageData = metadata?[PhotosManager addExif:image metaData:metadata]:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);

                     if (imageData != nil)
                     {
                         [arrImageData addObject:imageData];
                         NSLog(@"Adding images :%i",index);

                         //--- Done adding all images.
                         if (index == arrImages.count)
                         {
                             isDone = true;
                             NSLog(@"Done adding all images with info!!");
                             completionHandler(arrImageData);
                         }
                         index++;
                     }
                 }
             }];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        completionHandler(nil);
    }
}];
}


typedef void (^PHAssetMetadataBlock)(UIImage *image,NSDictionary *metadata);

+(void)requestMetadata:(PHAsset *)asset withCompletionBlock:(PHAssetMetadataBlock)completionBlock
{
    PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *editOptions = [[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions alloc]init];
    editOptions.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
    [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editOptions completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info)
     {
         CIImage *CGimage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL];
         UIImage *image = contentEditingInput.displaySizeImage;

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             completionBlock(image,CGimage.properties);
         });

         CGimage = nil;
         image = nil;

     }];

    editOptions = nil;
    asset =nil;
}

+ (NSData *)addExif:(UIImage*)toImage metaData:(NSDictionary *)container
{



 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(toImage, 1.0f);
       // create an imagesourceref
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) imageData, NULL);

// this is the type of image (e.g., public.jpeg)
CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(source);

// create a new data object and write the new image into it
NSMutableData *dest_data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:imageData.length+2000];
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)dest_data, UTI, 1, NULL);

if (!destination) {
    NSLog(@"Error: Could not create image destination");
}

// add the image contained in the image source to the destination, overidding the old metadata with our modified metadata
CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) container);
BOOL success = NO;
success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Error: Could not create data from image destination");
}

CFRelease(destination);
CFRelease(source);
imageData = nil;
source = nil;
destination = nil;

return dest_data;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not a surprise that you arrive into this situation, since each of your image consumes memory and you instantiate and keep them in memory. This is not really a correct design approach.
In the end it depends on what you want to do with those images.

What I would suggest is that you keep just the array of your `PHAsset` objects and request the image only on demand.
Like if you want to represent those images into a tableView/collectionView, perform the call to

`[PhotosManager requestMetadata:asset withCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *metadata)`

directly in the particular method. This way you won't drain the device memory.

Comment: I want to send those image data to server and just want to show the count and size of images in tableview.

Comment: It doesn't matter in the end what you want to do and what you want to accomplish. You just have to understand that you can't keep all the images in the device memory, it just drains it and that's all. Just don't keep the images with metadata and whatever else you need in array. Instead, create some async methods, which obtains the image with it's metadata, applies whatever changes you need to it, and send it to the server and then release it.

Comment: Agree!! but still how can i overcome this situation?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, you just store the PHAsset array for general use. Extract the image only when you need to send it to the server.

Comment: You can also iterate through the PHAsset array to extract the image sizes and keep it in a separate array.

Answer (score 0):

There simply is not enough memory on the phone to load all of the images into the photo library into memory at the same time.

If you want to display the images, then only fetch the images that you need for immediate display.  For the rest keep just he `PHAsset`.  Make sure to discard the images when you don't need them any more.

If you need thumbnails, then fetch only the thumbnails that you need.

If want to do something with all of the images - like add a watermark to them or process them in some way - then process each image one at a time in a queue.

I cannot advise further as your question doesn't state *why* you need all of the images.

Comment: to send image to server app. [i'm using GCDAsyncSocket to send data on receiver socket/port.] and i don't have that much waiting time to request images from PHAsset while sending on socket/port.